I cant access all my private repos with root user on AWS ECR: with an explicit deny in a service control policy
Please i need some help on this issue with my AWS Account
I logged in to the account today and i couldn't access all my Private Repos in my ECR with root user.
Please any tips on what to do will be very helpful
thanks
> `API error
> User: arn:aws:iam:XXXXXXXX:root is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetRegistryScanningConfiguration on resource: * with an explicit deny in a service control policy
> 
> API error
> User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXX:root is not authorized to perform: ecr:DescribeRepositories on resource: arn:aws:ecr:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:repository/* with an explicit deny in a service control policy`



The error message is clear. You have a service control policy preventing access.
